# Java minesweeper method to add numbers around bombs not working right

Tags: java, minesweeper

I wrote this method for my java minesweeper game, it is supposed to check spots surrounding a set of coordinates and then calculate how many bombs are near by.

```
public void numberMines(){
    int count = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xMin = x-1;
    int xMax = x+1;
    int yMin = y-1;
    int yMax = y+1; 
    if (x == 0){
        xMin = 0;
    }
    if (y == 0){
        yMin = 0;   //these restrictions take care of the spots in the edges
    }
    if (x == rows){
        xMax = rows;
    }
    if (y == columns){
        yMax = columns;
    }
    //first 2 loops go through every spot on the board
    for (x=0; x<rows; x++){
        for (y=0; y<columns; y++){
            //if the spot selected is not a bomb, for loops check spaces surrounding it
            if (mineBoard[x][y] != bomb){
                for (int i = xMin; i <=xMax; i++){
                    for (int j = yMin; j <=yMax; j++){
                        if (mineBoard[i][j] == bomb){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (count > 0){       //converts them characters
                mineBoard[x][y] = (char)(count + '0');
                count = 0;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Every time I run this method it returns 3,2,1, or empty so it does count how many bombs are around, but for some reason it is over looping and returning the same thing for every spot that is not a bomb after the first one. I really cant see where I messed up, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Move this block of code:

```
int xMin = x-1;
int xMax = x+1;
int yMin = y-1;
int yMax = y+1; 
if (x == 0){
    xMin = 0;
}
if (y == 0){
    yMin = 0;   //these restrictions take care of the spots in the edges
}
if (x == rows){
    xMax = rows;
}
if (y == columns){
    yMax = columns;
}
```

Inside of your for loops:

```
for (x=0; x<rows; x++){
    for (y=0; y<columns; y++){
       //Insert code here <---
```

Because at the moment, you're doing these calculations *once*, for x=0, y=0.

---

The code would probably also look cleaner if you moved the setting of `count` to 0 just before the `i`,`j`, loops, and not having it done once before all loops start, and again inside the conditional that displays the result.

---

Based on your comment - I think your valid indexes range from `0..(rows-1)` and `0..(columns-1)` - so you have a fencepost error also. Modify these lines:

```
if (x == rows-1){
    xMax = rows-1;
}
if (y == columns-1){
    yMax = columns-1;
}
```

But still have this entire block inside of your `x`/`y` loops. You don't get the out of bounds error when they're outside because you never calculate `xMax` and `yMax` when `x` and `y` are at their maximum values.

Comment: but if I add that block of code inside, it shows me an out of bounds error

Comment: @FacundoEzequielCandido - see update at bottom - `x` will never equal `rows` - its maximum possible value is `rows-1`. Similar statement for `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to declare all variables at the beginning of a method, better declare them close to when they are *used*. To fix your problem, you need to compute count, xMin, xMax, yMin and yMax in the loops like this:

```
public void numberMines(){
    //first 2 loops go through every spot on the board
    for (int x=0; x<rows; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<columns; y++){
            int count = 0;
            //if the spot selected is not a bomb, for loops check spaces surrounding it
            if (mineBoard[x][y] != bomb){
                for (int i = (x == 0 ? 0 : x-1); i <= (x == rows ? rows : x+1); i++){
                    for (int j = (y == 0 ? 0 : y-1); j <= (y == rows ? rows : y+1); j++){
                        if (mineBoard[i][j] == bomb){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (count > 0){       //converts them characters
                mineBoard[x][y] = (char)(count + '0');
            }
         }
    }
}
```

I have inlined the boundary checks, which is not necessary, but makes the code shorter to present here.